# Joining on the previous month data for each month in the PySpark dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataset which is on a monthly basis and each month has N-number of accounts. Some months will have new accounts and some accounts will disappear after a certain month(this is randomly done).

I need to get an account's current month balance and deduct it from the previous month's balance (if this account existed in the previous month) otherwise have it as the current month's balance.

I was suggested to do a join on each month. i.e. join month1 to month2, month2 to month3, etc. But I am not exactly sure how that would go...

Here is an example dataset:

```py
|date      |account   |balance   |
----------------------------------
|01.01.2019|1         |40        |
|01.01.2019|2         |33        |
|01.01.2019|3         |31        |
|01.02.2019|1         |32        |
|01.02.2019|2         |56        |
|01.02.2019|4         |89        |
|01.03.2019|2         |12        |
|01.03.2019|4         |35        |
|01.03.2019|5         |76        |
|01.03.2019|6         |47        |
----------------------------------
```

The account id is unique for each gone, current and new-coming account.

I initially used f.lag, but now that there are accounts that dissapear and come in new, the number of accounts per month is not constant, so I cannot lag. As I said I was suggested to use join. I.e. join Jan onto Feb, Feb onto March, etc.

But I am not really sure how that would go. Anyone has any ideas ?

P.S. I created this table with example of an account that stays, an account that is new and an account that is removed from later months.

**The end goal is:**

```py
|date      |account   |balance   | balance_diff_with_previous_month  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|01.01.2019|1         |40        |na                                |
|01.01.2019|2         |33        |na                                |
|01.01.2019|3         |31        |na                                |
|01.02.2019|1         |32        |-8                                |
|01.02.2019|2         |56        |23                                |
|01.02.2019|4         |89        |89                                |
|01.03.2019|2         |12        |-44                               |
|01.03.2019|4         |35        |-54                               |
|01.03.2019|5         |76        |76                                |
|01.03.2019|6         |47        |47                                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

As I said, f.lag cannot be used because the number of accounts per month is not constant and I do not control the number of accounts, therefore cannot f.lag a constant amount of rows.

Anyone has any ideas about how joining on account and/or date(current month) with date-1 (previous month)?

Thanks for reading and helping :)

Comment: can you explain value of your output, I am not understanding how you are calculating balance diff of date 01.03.2019 for account 2 , which is -20 in you case , can you please explain formula and also for account 4 which should -54 instead of -44 (35 - 89)

Comment: I corrected the numbers. Apologies. My quick maths was bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F.lag` works perfectly for what you want if you partition by `account` and

```
partition = Window.partitionBy("account") \
                  .orderBy(F.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))

previousAmount = data.withColumn("balance_diff_with_previous_month", F.lag("balance").over(partition))
                     .show(10, False)
```

Comment: I believe this works. I will give it more testing with real data and then accept your answer if it still works (i expect it to do).thanks a lot !

Comment: I have not used Window functions a lot and I am not very familiar, but why do we need the .cast("long") at the end of the first line ? 

Also assuming that the date column will come in as date, can we ommit the cast("timestamp") ?

Comment: The casting as long is not necessary but it's just a formalism for timestamp

Answer (score 2):

alternate solution using joins ....

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
            ("01.01.2019", 1, 40),("01.01.2019", 2, 33),("01.01.2019", 3, 31),
            ("01.02.2019", 1, 32), ("01.02.2019", 2, 56),("01.02.2019", 4, 89),
            ("01.03.2019", 2, 12),("01.03.2019", 4, 35),("01.03.2019", 5, 76),("01.03.2019", 6, 47)],
            ["date","account","balance"])

df.alias("current").join(
    df.alias("previous"),
    [F.to_date(F.col("previous.date"), "dd.MM.yyyy") == F.to_date(F.add_months(F.to_date(F.col("current.date"), "dd.MM.yyyy"),-1),"dd.MM.yyyy"), F.col("previous.account") == F.col("current.account")],
    "left"
).select(
    F.col("current.date").alias("date"),
    F.coalesce("current.account", "previous.account").alias("account"),
    F.col("current.balance").alias("balance"),
    (F.col("current.balance") - F.coalesce(F.col("previous.balance"), F.lit(0))).alias("balance_diff_with_previous_month")
).orderBy("date","account").show()
```

which results

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
|      date|account|balance|balance_diff_with_previous_month|
+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
|01.01.2019|      1|     40|                              40|
|01.01.2019|      2|     33|                              33|
|01.01.2019|      3|     31|                              31|
|01.02.2019|      1|     32|                              -8|
|01.02.2019|      2|     56|                              23|
|01.02.2019|      4|     89|                              89|
|01.03.2019|      2|     12|                             -44|
|01.03.2019|      4|     35|                             -54|
|01.03.2019|      5|     76|                              76|
|01.03.2019|      6|     47|                              47|
+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: I will keep it in mind. But it looks like a lot of extra rows of code compared to the bottom @LaSul's answer. Thank you very much for the response!

Comment: You can check the performance for both options instead of no of lines of code. In general window functions are expensive, but you can check the performance of using window + lag vs join for your dataset and use the best one.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> from pyspark.sql import Window
>>> df.show()
+----------+-------+-------+
|      date|account|balance|
+----------+-------+-------+
|01.01.2019|      1|     40|
|01.01.2019|      2|     33|
|01.01.2019|      3|     31|
|01.02.2019|      1|     32|
|01.02.2019|      2|     56|
|01.02.2019|      4|     89|
|01.03.2019|      2|     12|
|01.03.2019|      4|     35|
|01.03.2019|      5|     76|
|01.03.2019|      6|     47|
+----------+-------+-------+

>>> df1 = df.withColumn("date", expr("to_date(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')"))
>>> W = Window.partitionBy("account").orderBy("date")
>>> df1.withColumn("balance_diff_with_previous_month", col("balance") - lag(col("balance"),1,0).over(W)).show()
+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
|      date|account|balance|balance_diff_with_previous_month|
+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
|2019-01-01|      1|     40|                            40.0|
|2019-01-01|      2|     33|                            33.0|
|2019-01-01|      3|     31|                            31.0|
|2019-02-01|      1|     32|                            -8.0|
|2019-02-01|      2|     56|                            23.0|
|2019-02-01|      4|     89|                            89.0|
|2019-03-01|      2|     12|                           -44.0|
|2019-03-01|      4|     35|                           -54.0|
|2019-03-01|      5|     76|                            76.0|
|2019-03-01|      6|     47|                            47.0|
+----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
```